# Real Time Inference Pipeline without Designer

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service

i am currently getting into Azure Machine Learning. I am trying out the learning path for Data Scientists. In that learning path, the Designer is introduced, where Pipelines are being published to be consumed as a real time inference pipeline.

Since I dont want to use the Designer all the time I want to do the same in python. All the tutorials on Microsoft Learn only show how to deploy a single model as a service (e.g. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/register-and-deploy-model-with-amls/). In those tutorials pipelines are only created to train models, but not for predictions on incoming data (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-pipelines-in-aml/). An entry script is used to load incoming data into the pretrained model. For me it is not clear how to implement pipeline steps inside this entry script. I checked online, but I couldnt find any explanation how to do this in a satisfying way. Is there a tutorial of any sort out there to do this?

I am thinking about those pipeline steps, because I would like to do some preprocessing to incoming data using the same scaler I used for training my model. In my eyes loading the training database every time new data is coming in to fit a scaler to the training dataset, seems way of an overload for (near-)real-time models.

I am guessing there is an easy way to do all this, but using the resources I found online, I couldnt come up with a suitable solution for this.

Best regards and Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The “score.py” exposed in trained_model_outputs is for customized deployment, only have model init and scoring logic, user can add their own pre-process and post-process code on top of that.
The scoring logic that having pre-process logic is available through Designer deployed web service, which can be on both AKS and ACI. You can follow this doc: Tutorial: [Deploy ML models with the designer - Azure Machine Learning | Microsoft Docs](https://review.learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/tutorial-designer-automobile-price-deploy?branch=release-build-2021-azureml).

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-model-designer),Basically you can register a trained model in Designer bring it out with SDK/CLI to deploy it.

Sharing a reference [notebook](https://github.com/nfmoore/aml-designer-iot-edge/blob/main/00-containerize-designer-model.ipynb) from Nicholas.

How to deploy using environments can be found here [model-register-and-deploy.ipynb](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/deployment/deploy-to-cloud/model-register-and-deploy.ipynb) .  InferenceConfig class accepts  source_directory and entry_script [parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azureml-core/azureml.core.model.inferenceconfig?view=azure-ml-py#parameters), where source_directory  is a path to the folder that contains all files(score.py and any other additional files) to create the image.
This [multi-model-register-and-deploy.ipynb](https://github.com/Azure/MachineLearningNotebooks/blob/master/how-to-use-azureml/deployment/deploy-multi-model/multi-model-register-and-deploy.ipynb) has code snippets on how to create InferenceConfig with source_directory and entry_script.

Comment: Hello, thanks for those suggestions. To be honest, the actual issue I am having is not that I dont know how to register the model. When I infere data over a REST interface it needs to be preprocessed, for example using the same scaler used during training (or same labelEncoder etc.). What I dont understand so far is how to retrieve the same scaler again for incoming predictions over my api.

Comment: Hi. I am facing the exact same challenges, did you come up with a good solution?

Comment: Hey @Avocado, sorry for my late reply. I think I finally made it work. You can register the scaler model in your workspace and load it again in your scoring script. Basically load multiple models inside the scoring script than. This solved it for me. I also tried saving the pkl-File to my blob Storage and retrieving it, but that somehow messed up my scaler-model (even though I think AZ ML doesnt do anything else). Hope that helps :)